# Link error with boost::archive::test_oarchive using gcc OS X

Tags: c++, macos, gcc, boost

I'm building a project that requires boost's text_oarchive function, and am getting a linker error when trying to build it.

I've installed Boost 1.55.0 on OS X 10.9

My compiler information is reported as:
$g++ --version

Configured with: --prefix=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr --with-gxx-include-dir=/usr/include/c++/4.2.1
Apple LLVM version 5.0 (clang-500.2.79) (based on LLVM 3.3svn)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin13.0.0
Thread model: posix

The bootstrap.log file in the boost directory reports the "'darwin' toolset" was used.
however, when building from Eclipse, the following error is reported at the end of the build output:

```
"boost::archive::detail::basic_oarchive::~basic_oarchive()", referenced from:
::archive::detail::common_oarchive<boost::archive::text_oarchive>::~common_oarchive() in         msgQueProducer.o
"typeinfo for boost::archive::archive_exception", referenced from:
void boost::serialization::throw_exception<boost::archive::archive_exception>         (boost::archive::archive_exception const&) in msgQueProducer.o
"typeinfo for boost::archive::detail::basic_oarchive", referenced from:
typeinfo for boost::archive::detail::common_oarchive<boost::archive::text_oarchive> in msgQueProducer.o
"vtable for boost::archive::archive_exception", referenced from:
boost::archive::archive_exception::archive_exception(boost::archive::archive_exception const&) in msgQueProducer.o

NOTE: a missing vtable usually means the first non-inline virtual member function has no definition.

ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64

clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
make: *** [msgQueProducer] Error 1
```

The project builds fine when the following single line of code removed from the project:

```
boost::archive::text_oarchive oa(oss);
```

I'm wondering if when I built the boost libraries I should have specified some architecture parameters (passing to the ./b2 tool something like "./b2 toolset=darwin cxxflags="-arch i386" address-model=64 architecture=x86 stage").  However, I'm building with another boost function used for interprocess messaging, and the project builds fine with it included.

The boost project includes I'm using are:

```
#include <boost/interprocess/ipc/message_queue.hpp>
#include <boost/archive/text_oarchive.hpp>
```

What do I need to do to use boost::text_oarchive on my OS X system?

Thanks in advance, 
Walt

Comment: are you linking the boost-serialization library?

Comment: That was what was needed.  I've added -lboost_serialization to the linker path and it now builds correctly.   Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to link the boost-serialization library. Add `-lboost_serialization` to your `LDFLAGS`.